# No reconoce el as name con SQL Server y Laravel

Tags: sql-server, laravel

Estoy realizando un `select` de `branch_id`, `month`. Lo que trato de realizar es contar los registros de la fecha.

El problema surge cuando hago el `DB::raw('MONTH(tic_date_in) month')`, no me reconoce el `as month` en el `groupBy('month')`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy trabajando con Sql Server.

Comment: El código y las trazas de error, siempre como texto y no como imágenes (hace más difícil replicar los errores). :)

Comment: el `as` del `DB::raw(COUNT(*)` ?

Comment: El `as` de `DB::raw('MONTH(tic_date_in) month')` incluso  pongo in el `as` pero en el `groupBy` no me reconoce el `month`

Comment: Intenta en el alias poner as [month]

Comment: te falta poner el `as` antes de `month` o no?

Comment: No se puede ordenar por una columna que no existe. El as en el select se agrega despues de realizada la consulta, y el order mucho antes, por lo tanto esa columna no existe. Para ordenar por esa columna, o trabajas con un subquery, o le pasas al order by la funcion que termina siendo ese campo.

Comment: El error es que no reconoce el alias  `month` en el `groupBy`. Y esto solo pasa con SQL Server.

Comment: gbianchi te dio la respuesta, tendrias que hacer un subquery y agrupar en ese caso por el alias..

Comment: Alan, esto te va a pasar en montones de bases de datos. Porque los motores de SQL funcionan asi.